# How to identify specific chipset driver on client to add to WDS driver database?

Tags: drivers, wds, chipset

I have two new models to support, Optiplex 790 and Lenovo L520. I need to add their chipset drivers to the Windows Deployment server and Intel's driver package is a suite of chipset drivers. WDS discovers way too many:

[image: WDS driver wizard]

Prior to installing the chipset, SM_Bus shows a yellow exclamation in the Device Manager. When I install Intel's suite, the drivers are installed and SM_Bus is gone.  How can I identify which drivers are being used?

Answer (score 2):

The readme for the Intel chipset provides a command line option that extracts the relevant drivers to C:\Program Files\Intel\InfInst:

-AONLY

```
            Extracts the needed INF files to install on the
            current system. If the install has been run once
            successfully, '-AONLY' will not return any INFs
            when used in conjunction with '-OVERALL' switch, 
            all the needed INFs for the system will be 
            extracted.
```

Answer (score 1):

port installation, open the Intel log file, scroll to the bottom; find the .inf files used to deploy the correct chip set drivers to the OS